# Appium iOS Real Device Testing-Error: Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1

Tags: ios, bash, shell, automation, appium

- Device: iPhone 5SE (Real Device)
- Version: 9.3.2
- Appium Version: 1.6.3
- [Appium log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw209KxHVRKITU5lc082ZjI5Y0U/view?usp=sharing)
- ios-debug-proxy is on.

When i tried to run my test, ı faced this error.

> Error: Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1

What is the solution of the this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like carthage is not installed.
Please install `brew install carthage` and try again.